# Trouble understanding indexing array

Tags: c

```
void addChar() {
    if (lexLen <= 98) {
        lexeme[lexLen++] = nextChar;
        lexeme[lexLen] = 0;
    } else {
        printf("Error - lexeme is too long \n");
    }
}
```

This is a snippet from a simple lexical analyzer...
I'm not sure what the line `lexeme[lexLen++] = nextChar;`  does.
And in the next line, why does it assign 0 to lexLen.

It's original comment said its to add nextChar into lexeme, but I don't get how it does that.

Comment: `lexLen++` is a postfix increment, so you are setting 0 on higher index in the lexeme array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lexeme` is an array of `char` or a pointer to the first `char` in an array of `char`.

`lexLen` is the number of characters currently in the array, before a null character that marks the end of the string being built.

In `lexeme[lexLen++] = nextChar;`:

- `lexeme[lexLen]` (ignore the `++` for the moment) is the element in the array that currently contains the null character marking the end.
- `lexeme[lexLen] = nextChar;` changes that element to contain the value in `nextChar`. Thus, it puts this character from `nextChar` at the end of the string in the array.
- The `++` increments `lexLen` after its value is used for the above.

`lexeme[lexLen] = 0;` puts a null character in the position after the end of the lengthened string, to mark its new end.

Answer (score 0):

Add nextChar after the original string, then add '\0' at the end, this is a C style string.

At the same time, if the length of string more than 98, print error message

Answer (score 0):

Lexeme is an array of characters. Gven the range checks I am going to assume it's 100 characters long and it's already had memory allocated. Your code does not show that.

lexLen is a number. It would appear to be pointing at the end of your string. So if Lexeme currently contains "hello", lexLen will be 5.

```
lexeme[lexLen++] = nextChar;
```

This line does two things. It says "the character at position 5 in lexeme should be set to nextchar. It also increments lexLen (++), so lexLen is now 6.

```
lexeme[lexLen] = 0;
```

This says "the character at position 6 in lexeme should be set to 0". This is because strings in C should be null terminated. (0 == null). The null marks the end of the string. The next time AddChar() is called it will be overwritten.